# Make stackoverflow.stackexchange.com redirect to StackOverflow

Tags: feature-request

While I admit that it is a bit goofy, but because StackOverflow is a StackExchange site, it seems like it would be reasonable to expect that stackoverflow.stackexchange.com would redirect to stackoverflow directly. Could superuser.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.stackexchange.com, and serverfault.stackexchange.com be updated to redirect people to the actual websites?